# Firebase DB data security

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

sorry if this is kind of a noob question.

Let's say I was developing a chat app with the use of the Firebase Real-time Database. When I look into the Firebase Console I can see all the messages my users send.

Can I prevent this somehow?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. As an admin with access to the console, you'll always have full access to everything.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440491/firebase-set-data-structure/39441920#39441920